# MYSQL Range criteria is applied only for indexed columns

Tags: mysql

I am executing the below query to get daily user signin details from my table . I posted the sample table and the query i am executing .

**Problem**

My Query is not executing as `range` query it examines the whole table . It becomes slow for me . If I index the timestamp column is not useful because there is no major differnce between timestamp in  milliseconds .  I couldn't do indexing the timestamp column for a table because my product in a production setup . It will contains millions of rows. How can execute this query as a `range` one or any better solutions?

**MYSQL Table**
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                          |

```
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SignInDetails | CREATE TABLE `SignInDetails` (
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserName` char(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Query**

```
select USER_ID,TIMESTAMP from SignInDetails where TIMESTAMP 
between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY)*1000 and 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE())*1000
```

Explain Output

```
    +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SignInDetails | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   21 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

**Total Rows In a table**

21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desc output doesn't indicate that `timestamp` is indexed column. Can you provide the DDL, so that we can see that you actually creating an index for it?

Alternatively, you could use 2 columns to store the timestamp with milliseconds resolution, one is used for search and the other for extra resolution. I can imagine combinations: `datetime`/`msec`, `date`/`bigint-msec`, `datetime`/`bigint-msec`. Actual combination is going to depend on what kind of queries are used most frequently.

Comment: Actually what i actually mean is am not created index for the timestamp column . Please read me question once again  "I couldn't do indexing the timestamp column for a table because my product in a production setup" . Is index is useful for timestamp column?

Comment: If i understand you correctly now. In order to search through data efficiently you need indexing it in most cases. If the query you provided is the only type of select you run on the table it probably would make sense to add a `date` type column and index it instead, because your index on your bigint column could be less efficient in this case. You also could look into [MySQL Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) and partition your data by day.